# Some countries are disabled in google play developer console

Tags: android, google-play

Chinese users reported that they're not able to download my application encountering "This item cannot be installed on your country" message.
So I checked the "pricing and distribution" section of my developer console. As you can see in the image, "China" filed is disabled. Some other countries such as "Iran", "Myanmar" and even "Rest of the word" are disabled as well.
[image]

Comment: you can't publish your apps in those country as i here in Iran, can't access apps in google play store ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The likely reason you are unable to select China and the rest of the world to distribute to in the Developer Console is because your app contains the BILLING permission. 
The BILLING permission makes apps that are free be treated as if they're paid. If you remove this permission, you should be able to select China and the rest of the world.

Comment: Can you back what you wrote with a link to some formal documentation?

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar problem.

1. There is a permission `"<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING">"` in my AndroidManifest.xml
2. If you add this permission in your AndroidManifest.xml, you can not publish your app in some countries like China, Myanmar and so on.
3. Personally，my app need to be published in Myanmar. So I delete this permission from AndroidManifest.xml. Then,it works to me.

Answer (score 0):

I heard the following,

Because in some countries they block google  due to some constraints

So there is no support for google for those countries